# PHP session_set_cookie_params break php session_start() function and $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm trying to create a secure session by creating `start_secure_session()` function like this:

```
function start_secure_session() {
    $session_name   = 'secure_session';
    $secure         = true;
    $httponly       = true;

    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === false) {
        die('error');
    }

    $cookie_params  = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookie_params["lifetime"],
        $cookie_params["path"],
        $cookie_params["domain"],
        $secure,
        $httponly);

    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

The problem is, `start_secure_session()` is not saving `$_SESSION` super global variable. It's unset immediately when the page refreshed. It works only if I comment this out:

```
    //$cookie_params    = session_get_cookie_params();
    //session_set_cookie_params($cookie_params["lifetime"],
    //  $cookie_params["path"],
    //  $cookie_params["domain"],
    //  $secure,
    //  $httponly);
```

or in other words, not setting a custom cookie params.

What should I do to make it works? So, the `session_start()` can work properly and `$_SESSION` variable can remember it's value?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the secure=TRUE and you not using HTTPS? 
It will not create a session on a non-secure connection with secure set to TRUE.